# Not able to render react component inside List component of MUI

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, material-ui

CustomButtons is a separate React component which consists of of several buttons like login, etc

I want this CustomButtons component to appear when I call this list function :

```
const list=()=>{ 
   <Box>  
     <List> 
       <ListItem button> 
         <CustomButtons/> 
       </ListItem> 
    </List> 
   </Box> 
}
```

List and ListItem, I am importing from @mui/material and CustomButtons is a separate custom made react component that I am importing as well